# Change or Add a Default Editor in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to add a new (external) default editor for a file type in Visual Studio 2012. My editor (Notepad++) supports jumping directly to a specific line via programme arguments. Sadly the [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy2sthf1.aspx) doesn't mention any macro parameters to use the line (and character) offset in a given context (i.e. when double clicking a search result).

Is it possible to get the line and/or character offset in the *Arguments* field in *Add Program*?

[image: AddProgrammeDialog]

Edit: Is there a way to access these open-events through extensions with information about the file, line and the chosen opening programme?

Answer (score 7):

Using `$(ItemPath) -n$(CurLine)` as arguments did the work for me:

[image]

Comment: Sadly this only works if the file is already open in the text editor of Visual Studio which I'm trying to avoid. When I apply the same arguments to the Add Program dialog as an external editor the macros `$(...)` don't seem to be resolved as Notepad++ opens with *C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\$(ItemPath) doesn't exist. Create it?*

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Oh. I see. From where do you want to open it?

Comment: Primarily from the *Find Results* window

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I've looked in a lot of places, I didn't find any relevant solution... Good luck with this one, I doubt it's possible...

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I'll update my question once I get any further myself, but for the moment I'm stuck

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I don't know if you've planned to look with `ProcMon` but there is nothing interesting to see on this side :/

Comment: @Thomas Do you see any way to improve your suggestion by the "Promt for arguments" Parameter. Feel free use imag http://i.stack.imgur.com/dRwb6.jpg Then I delete this part from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible by default, because there are no [Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ekbzk5f8%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) reflecting the Search-Result. So you have first open the File inside VisualStudio and then with external Tool.

I think you could create a custom Visual-Studio Plugin and hook inside the selection of your search-Results. Look at [Adding Search to a Tool Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266761.aspx) available for VS 2015, 2013 and 2012. Some Implementation this way seems to be [Quick Open File Plugin for VS2010](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3eb2f230-2728-4d5f-b448-4c0b64154da7) but a textbox to enter the linenumber is missing.

More Documentation to create VS Plugins on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx)

Btw, have you Checked the "Promt for arguments" Option to extend Thomas answer:

[image: External Tools VS Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a solution to this that takes 2 steps, both of which take little time once you have your search results.  `Double-click the result`, `press ctrl-shift-alt-L` (can be changed of course).

The steps below are verbose to show as much as possible so everyone can understand the steps and modify accordingly.

**Create a cmd file that will launch notepad++ with file, line, and column arguments**

Save the code below in `d:\util\startnppwith3args.cmd`

```
setlocal
set _file=%0
set _line=%1
set _column=%2
set _line=%_line:"=%
set _column=%_column:"=%
: remember to use "" as first arg as blank title so we call npp properly :)
start "" "F:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession -n%_line% -c%_column% %_file%
pause
endlocal
```

**Create external tool to call startnppwith3args.cmd**

`tools | External Tools...`

[image]

*Remember the position of this command, 3 in this case.*

**Create a keyboard shortcut to "command3"**

`tools | Options | Keyboard` and search for `externalcommand`

[image]

Assign your desired key combination to this command `ctrl-shift-alt L` for example.

**Verify your command is as expected on the Tools menu**

[image]

**Now put it all into action**

- Open a file in Visual Studio
- Search for something in the file
- Double-click desired search result
- Press `ctrl-shift-alt L`

Notepad++ opens up the file on the line and column for the search result!

[image]

**What's left?**

- Take the `pause` out of the cmd file as it was used just for debugging purposes.
- decide if you want `-multiInst -nosession` arguments
- Take a look at [Arguments for External Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekbzk5f8(v=vs.120).aspx) for all variables that are assigned when you launch an external tool.

**Conclusion**

This was in interesting question, and an area I had not explored before.  I might use this technique myself and for other purposes.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get the line & col position from one specific search result source code line (the one you double-click on), which is what OP wants, only the current line & col position of the 'Find Results' Tool Window, which is not the same at all.

Comment: When you double-click the search result, you are brought to the line and column of the result.  The external tool launches with this information.  I called this out as the 2-step solution at the top of my post.

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't see that. However, IMHO it's not a satisfying enough answer :-)

Comment: thanks but I'm really trying to avoid opening the file in the internal editor in the first place as it starts a buggy background process for large xaml files - so far opening it in the external editor (which works by setting it as the default editor) then "go to line" is doing the best job for me...